# nasm program printing more arguments than it should

Tags: linux, command-line, nasm

I am writing a simple program where I am supposed to get the first command line argument and print it out to the standard output. 
My code looks like this:

```
section .bss
env resb 100

section .text
global _start
_start:
mov rbp, rsp

add rbp, 16
mov rsi, arg
mov rsi, [rbp]

mov rax, 1
mov rdi, 1
mov rdx, 100
syscall
```

So when I call my program from the Linux terminal, like this: `./program hello`, I expect it to print out "hello". But the output looks like this: `helloLC_PAPER=bs_BA.UTF-8XDG_VTNR=7LC_ADDRESS=bs_BA.UTF-8SSH_AGENT_PID=1483XDG_SESSION_ID=c2LC`. 
I understand that these are the environmental variables, but I just can't figure out why they get printed out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You aren't showing the code that actually prints out the string. So it's hard to answer this one. But I suspect that whatever you're calling to print the string either expects a string terminating character that you did not provide, or it expects you to provide the length of the string in a register which you did not provide.

Comment: If you're using `syscall` 4 (`sys_write`) then one of the arguments must be the length of the buffer (string in this case) being written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually if you check carefully you will observe that 100 characters are printed, starting from the address of "hello" in the memory.

Replace

```
mov rdx, 100
```

with

```
mov rdx, 5 ; len of "hello", instead of 100
```